# Using variable in setting mysql INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT table value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, auto-increment

I try to (re)set the auto_increment value to the value of a variable, but it fails:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
SET @tmpvar = 12345;
ALTER TABLE test_table AUTO_INCREMENT=@tmpvar;
```

The last command fails with:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@tmpvar' at line 1
```

Is it not possible to set the AUTO_INCREMENT value like this? What are the alternatives? I need to set this value in a stored procedure that rotates log tables and I need the new table to start with values taken from some old table.

*Addendum*

The direct creation of the table with the correct auto increment intial value fails as well:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=@tmpvar;
```

P.S. I found a related question here on So, but with no answer: [Updating auto_increment value in an InnoDB table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409274/updating-auto-increment-value-in-an-innodb-table)

*EDIT*
corrected missing semicolon

Comment: Use [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: Missing ; before the SET command

Comment: @Shadow - i corrected this. This is not the problem though.

Comment: @wchiquito would you care to explain how to prepare an alter table statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

SET @`tmpvar` := 12345;

SET @`stmt_alter` := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `test_table` AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @`tmpvar`);

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`stmt_alter`;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/399aa/1)</kbd>

**UPDATE**

You can use [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) for [13.1.14 CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

```sql
SET @`tmpvar` := 12345;

SET @`stmt_create` := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=', @`tmpvar`);

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`stmt_create`;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e6c3/1)</kbd>

Comment: @Shadow: `User variables may be used in most contexts where expressions are permitted. This does not currently include contexts that explicitly require a literal value, such as in the LIMIT clause of a SELECT statement, or the IGNORE N LINES clause of a LOAD DATA statement.`. See [9.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: Yep, got that. I was too focussed on the error messages :(

Comment: It is working now. And I understand why it did not before. Thank you for pointing this out to me.